# Is there an efficient way to avoid UNIONs of fixed values in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, coding-style

For example with Oracle: I want some temporary table to be in used for a Merge:

```
MERGE INTO my_target_table
USING (
        WITH tbl1 AS (       SELECT 'a'   col1 FROM dual            -- <--- THIS
                       UNION SELECT 'foo' col1 FROM dual            -- <--- IS
                       UNION SELECT 'doh' col1 FROM dual            -- <--- CRAPPY
                     ),
             tbl2 AS (       SELECT 'b'   col2, 'c' col3 FROM dual  -- <--- THIS
                       UNION SELECT 'x'   col2, 's' col3 FROM dual  -- <--- ALSO
                     )
        SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl1 CROSS JOIN tbl2
      ) my_source_view
   ON (     my_target_table.col1 = my_source_view.col1
        AND my_target_table.col2 = my_source_view.col2
      )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
                      SET my_target_table.col3 = my_source_view.col3
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(               col1,                col2,                col3)
                       VALUES(my_source_view.col1, my_source_view.col2, my_source_view.col3)
;
```

The `SELECT UNION SELECT` pattern here is really annoying and I find it hideous (repetitive, verbose).

Do you have a trick to forge similar queries, be it Oracle specific or not?

Thank you

Comment: How about using a table to store the *fixed* values?

Comment: @dotjoe: How do you fill it quickly? `INSERT INTO the table SELECT UNION SELECT`.

Comment: couldn't you simply fill it once and reuse the table? or do the values change?

Comment: @dotjoe: Actually those are queries for one-time use but I often make such queries and the values and table names change.

Comment: maybe it looks crappy because of the dual table in oracle...when i do it in tsql it looks a little less crappy. Also, do you have to define the column name for every select? In tsql you only have to name the columns in the first select.

Comment: When you do have to do this, consider UNION ALL instead, so Oracle doesn't have to sort the stuff.

Comment: @EvilTeach: as told in an answer comment for a small number of values this will not degrade performance so much, and you even end up losing time typing the ALL.

Comment: @dotjoe: you need only name the columns in the first select in Oracle as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Benoit,

You can use this for tables with one column:

```
SQL> with tbl1 as
  2  ( select column_value col1
  3      from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('a','foo','doh'))
  4  )
  5  select *
  6    from tbl1
  7  /

COL1
------------------------------------------------------------
a
foo
doh

3 rows selected.
```

For more than one column you'd need to create two types (or use existing ones), like this:

```
SQL> create type ot is object
  2  ( col1 varchar2(1)
  3  , col2 varchar2(1)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create type ntt is table of ot;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> with tbl2 as
  2  ( select *
  3      from table(ntt(ot('b','c'),ot('x','s')))
  4  )
  5  select *
  6    from tbl2
  7  /

C C
- -
b c
x s

2 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thank you. I like the first part of this answer (for one-col tables). Probably another package could do it in a more generic way?

Comment: It's not a package, but a collection (nested table type). In the SYS schema there are several predefined ones you can use. "odcivarchar2List" from another answer is one you can use as well. And you can certainly create one yourself if you like.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use the `VALUES` clause. Not sure if this is available in Oracle or not but you do specifically request all techniques.

Example syntax

```
SELECT col1 FROM (VALUES ('a'),('foo'), ('doh')) T  (col1)
```

Comment: This is a great thing. Unfortunately Oracle won't allow that it seems.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this (as already indicated above, here are a few more)

all of these are from the asktom question:
http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/06/varying-in-lists.html
and
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425

```
var mystring varchar2
begin
:mystring := trim('a,foo,doh,b,x');
end;
/


SELECT 

    substr(v.mystring, v.start_of_string, v.next_comma_location - v.start_of_string) "The String"
      FROM (SELECT comma_location + 1 start_of_string,
                   mystring,
                   nvl(lead(comma_location, 1) over(ORDER BY comma_location), mystring_length + 1) AS 
    next_comma_location
              FROM (SELECT :mystring mystring,
                           instr(:mystring, ',', LEVEL) comma_location,
                           length(:mystring) mystring_length
                      FROM dual
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL < length(:mystring))) v
     WHERE v.start_of_string < v.next_comma_location;
```

--or
 http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/12/predefined-collections.html

```
 select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2List('a','foo','doh','b','x'));




 COLUMN_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------
a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
foo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
doh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
x
```

you can treat these as tables

Answer (score 1):

Well, I agree that

```
    SELECT 'a'   col1 FROM dual 
    UNION SELECT 'foo' col1 FROM dual 
    UNION SELECT 'doh' col1 FROM dual
```

is crappy. Would you agree that

```
    SELECT 'a'   col1 FROM dual 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'foo' col1 FROM dual 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'doh' col1 FROM dual
```

is not?

**EDIT**

If you don't like some part of the grammar, you might try dynamic SQL (but do realize that this is your personal preference, so try to restrain from doing it on bigger systems).

Here's a link http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/DynamicInLists.php

Comment: It is less but for my sample it is useless to optimize it (you even lost more time typing UNION ALL!). What I would like is for example some builtin way to transform a list to a temp table.

Comment: Basically you don't like the grammar because it is too verbose? If so, can you please update your question. I'll update my answer...

Comment: @Unreason: you're right, this is what I feel. Too verbose thus I have the feeling there must be some better way.

Comment: If you are worried about losing more time typing UNION ALL vice UNION, you are a very poor programmer indeed. Good programming is more about what is the best for the system not what saves the programmer 5 seconds in typing.

Comment: @HLGEM: those are for one-time, typed on keyboard, queries. So for this one as I know that the result will be the same because I am typing manually all my values to be unioned. This does not mean that when automating processes I won't use UNION ALL.